# Django, can I get reference objects included with a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Say I have these models:

models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ref_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharacterField(max_length=32)

class ItemDue(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    lots of other fields below
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to query the `ItemDue` objects but want to also include the `Item` with the query.

If I get a set of `ItemDue`s I can loop like this:

```
for item_due in ItemDue.objects.filter(some_criteria):
    print item_due.item.ref_id
```

However, when I did some performance tests, this is going back to the database to get the referenced `Item` object, so I have to run another query for each `ItemDue` to get the `Item.ref_id`. This makes a difference in a huge query, so I want to get the `Item.ref_id` along with the queryset to get the `ItemDue`s. I can do `.values('id', 'item__ref_id')` to get a dictionary of the `ItemDue` with the `id` and `item__ref_id`. So, I could use `.values('id', 'item__ref_id', ...)` for all fields in `ItemDue` but that would be a lot of work. Is there a simple way I can append to the values of a queryset to get that reference object, without spelling out ALL the fields in the `ItemDue` along with just the one extra field `item__ref_id`?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is some code run in the manage.py shell:

```
def check():
    start = datetime.now()
    print "Starting {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    index = 0
    item_rows = dict()
    print "Getting Items for PG and Parents {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)

    # items due for PG
    items = pg.item_due.all().filter(disabled=False).select_related()

    # Loop the parents, and chain their items due to the PG items due.
    for p in parents:
        items = itertools.chain(items, p.item_due.all().filter(disabled=False).select_related())
        index += 1
    print "All Items Retrieved {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    for item in items:
        pass
    print "Loop Items Complete {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    return item_rows

>>> rows = check()
Starting 0:00:00.000008
Getting Items for PG and Parents 0:00:00.000032
All Items Retrieved 0:00:00.004669
Loop Items Complete 0:00:00.022597
```

Notice the time it takes to loop the items and just `pass` is about .018 seconds.

Now I simply change the `pass` in the loop to `item.item.ref_id` and it takes a LOT longer.

```
def check():
    start = datetime.now()
    print "Starting {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    index = 0
    item_rows = dict()
    print "Getting Items for PG and Parents {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)

    # items due for PG
    items = pg.item_due.all().filter(disabled=False).select_related()

    # Loop the parents, and chain their items due to the PG items due.
    for p in parents:
        items = itertools.chain(items, p.item_due.all().filter(disabled=False).select_related())
        index += 1
    print "All Items Retrieved {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    for item in items:
        item.item.ref_id
    print "Loop Items Complete {0}".format(datetime.now() - start)
    return item_rows

>>> rows = check()
Starting 0:00:00.000007
Getting Items for PG and Parents 0:00:00.000031
All Items Retrieved 0:00:00.004712
Loop Items Complete 0:00:00.258209
```

From .018 seconds to run the loop to .25 seconds. Why does it take 13 times the time just to process the item.item.ref_id if it is getting it from the query already?

Comment: Something to notice, if I change the loop `for item in items:` to just `item.id` instead of `item.item.ref_id` it is back to the quick .018 seconds. So, why would this reference object lookup take so long if it is getting the `select_related()` objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to get related tables data in one query:

```
for item_due in ItemDue.objects.filter(some_criteria).select_related():
    print item_due.item.ref_id
```

Comment: Wow, how simple. I was just not searching correctly. Thanks. Let me append my question, because it seems something else is slowing this down.

Comment: @Furbeenator you generate as many queries as have parents in p (for p in parents: items = ..). And in next cycle queries are executes one by one to get results (to get item.item.ref_id). Until you actually try to get data django not execute query... So here you are not execute any db query: for item in items: pass

Comment: Ahhhh, you mean because they are Lazy QuerySets, they do not actually get data from the DB until accessed?

Comment: But why does it go fast to use `item.id` in the loop, but slow it way down when I use `item.item.ref_id`?

Comment: thats weird, shouldnt be difference

Comment: Maybe I have something else going on, but at least I know how to specify to get the related. Thanks a bunch!